# Parsing through log file and printing out regex backreferences

Tags: text-processing, logs, regular-expression

I want to parse my `/var/log/maillog` to print out the email addresses in `from=<>` and `to=<>` (mainly to do a quick check for false positives in the DNS RBLs that I've configured)

A maillog entry looks like this (postfix):

```
Jun 20 17:27:52 foobarserver postfix/smtpd[15925]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from sbr.nouveauquebec.com[184.22.154.110]: 554 5.7.1 Service unavailable; Sender address [corporate@nouveauquebec.com] blocked using urired.spameatingmonkey.net; Red listed, see http://spameatingmonkey.com/lookup/nouveauquebec.com; from=<something@spam.com> to=<foo@foo.bar> proto=ESMTP helo=<sbr.nouveauquebec.com>
```

and my regex is

```
from=<(\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b)> to=<(\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b)>
```

I'm storing the matches in back references `\1` and `\2` which I want to print out. What I want to do is pipe the output from `cat /var/log/maillog` and apply the regex on each line and output the backreferences.

Is there a quick way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **sed**:

```
sed -r -n 's/^.* from=<([^>]+)>\s*to=<([^>]+)>.*$/\1 \2/p' /var/log/maillog
```

Answer (score 2):

This one uses a simplified regex and non-greedy quantifiers:

```
perl -ne 's/^.*from=<(.+?@.+?)> to=<(.+?@.+?)>.*$/$1 $2/; print;' /var/log/maillog
```